# How do you retrieve the min and max of time series data

Tags: pandas, numpy, matplotlib, time-series

I want to use matplotlib to shade between the minimum and maximum values of my timeseries data. Here is a sample of the data. How do i retrieve the min and max. (note that time given below is in string format but i have the time in seconds from previous day 00:00:00 so i have time as 5902761,5902770)

e.g

```
index       time            value
   1    08:00:00         100
   2    08:00:01         100
   3    08:00:01         101
   4    08:00:02         100
   5    08:00:02         102
   6    08:00:02         101
```

What i want is the following

```
index       time        min_value   max_value
   1      08:00:00         100         100
   2      08:00:01         100         101
   3      08:00:02         100         102
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.aggregate.html) with `rename`:

```
d = {'min':'min_value','max':'max_value'}
df = df.groupby('time')['value'].agg([min, max]).reset_index().rename(columns=d)
print (df)
       time  min_value  max_value
0  08:00:00        100        100
1  08:00:01        100        101
2  08:00:02        100        102
```

because:

```
df = df.groupby('time')['value'].agg({'min_value':'min','max_value':'max'})
```

> FutureWarning: using a dict on a Series for aggregation
>       is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
>         df = df.groupby('time')['value'].agg({'min':'min_value','max':'max_value'})