# Group data based on column name pandas

Tags: python, pandas

In the example below, I want to first sort based on UID and then the TSTAMP for each TID.

In this context, here is a minimal working example I generated:

```
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, names = ['TID','UID','TSTAMP'], delimiter=';')
df = df.sort_values(by=['TID'], ascending=[True])
print df
#print df.groupby('UID').describe()
```

However, this does not `groupby('UID')` the way want to sort it.

```
       TID   UID         TSTAMP
22267   77  (!?}  1494417075666
9095    77  U|X^  1494415815098
15266   77  ~Mb{  1494416401082
15263   77  ~Mb{  1494416401061
15255   77  Qh9~  1494416398799
15252   77  Qh9~  1494416398786
15239   77  xF#u  1494416397542
15236   77  xF#u  1494416397540
9105    77  U|X^  1494415815197
```

Something like this as the final result:

```
     TID      UID           TSTAMP
22267   77   (!?}   1494417075666
15263   77   ~Mb{   1494416401061
15266   77   ~Mb{   1494416401082
15252   77   Qh9~   1494416398786
15255   77   Qh9~   1494416398799
9095    77   U|X^   1494415815098
9105    77   U|X^   1494415815197
15236   77   xF#u   1494416397540
15239   77   xF#u   1494416397542
```

I'm a learning `pandas`.. any help will be appreciated.

Thanks to @jezrael, here is the final solution

```
df = pd.read_csv(dataset_path, names = ['TID','UID','TSTAMP'], delimiter=';')
df = df.sort_values(['TID', 'TSTAMP', 'UID'], ascending=[True, False, True])
d = {'min':'TSTAMP-INIT','max':'TSTAMP-FIN'}
df = df.groupby(['UID','TID'])['TSTAMP'].agg([min, max]).reset_index().rename(columns=d)

for i, row in df.T.iteritems():
    print row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html):

```
df = df.sort_values(['TID', 'TSTAMP', 'UID'], ascending=[True, False, True])
print (df)
       TID   UID         TSTAMP
22267   77  (!?}  1494417075666
15266   77  ~Mb{  1494416401082
15263   77  ~Mb{  1494416401061
15255   77  Qh9~  1494416398799
15252   77  Qh9~  1494416398786
15239   77  xF#u  1494416397542
15236   77  xF#u  1494416397540
9105    77  U|X^  1494415815197
9095    77  U|X^  1494415815098
```

If first column is not necessary sort, omit it:

```
df = df.sort_values(['TSTAMP', 'UID'], ascending=[False, True])
print (df)
       TID   UID         TSTAMP
22267   77  (!?}  1494417075666
15266   77  ~Mb{  1494416401082
15263   77  ~Mb{  1494416401061
15255   77  Qh9~  1494416398799
15252   77  Qh9~  1494416398786
15239   77  xF#u  1494416397542
15236   77  xF#u  1494416397540
9105    77  U|X^  1494415815197
9095    77  U|X^  1494415815098
```

Comment: I gave a bit more detail on the how the result should look like.. describe() gives me  lot of details that are not necessary for me

Comment: I am not sure about sorting in first column, if need `ascending=[True, False, True]` or `ascending=[False, False, True]`.

Comment: Is there a way to get the  first TSTAMP for a given UID and the last TSTAMP for the same UID?

For instance, for `~Mb{`: `1494416401082` and `1494416401061`

Comment: Yes, sure. Give me a sec.

Comment: I post answer a while ago - check it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43894135/2901002). Only need `df = df.groupby('UID')['TSTAMP'].agg([min, max]).reset_index().rename(columns=d)`

Comment: But then the TID column is gone. Should I say     `df = df.groupby(['UID','TID'])['TSTAMP'].agg([min, max]).reset_index().rename(columns=d)`
`

Comment: Then need `df.groupby('UID','TID')` like `df.groupby(['UID','TID'])`

Comment: This still doesn't allow me to get a specified UID's TID and TSTAMPs(Is there a pandas cheatsheet somewhere?)

Comment: Yes, but not sure if is for new version of pandas - check [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/master/doc/cheatsheet/Pandas_Cheat_Sheet.pdf)

Comment: What is `print (df.info())` ?

Comment: That's info regarding the dataframe isn't it?

Comment: Yes, becasue I try find what is problem. Btw, what is `error`? Or it count wrong?

Comment: I don't understand the questions. My question was, how do we obtain a `given/specified` UID's timestamps and TID?

Comment: Hmmm, I think  understand now.

Comment: ok, first create output dataframe `d = {'min':'min__val', 'max':'max_val'}`

Comment: and `df1 = df.groupby(['UID','TID'])['TSTAMP'].agg([min, max]).rename(columns=d)`

Comment: Oh, my apologies. I got that. Updating the question. Thanks